# Rails 3.1. How to make a menu builder output haml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, haml

I have been following a short [tutorial](http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=3899) to build a tab menu on my application.

This is menu_builder method in Applciation_helper

```
def menu_builder(page_id)
 tabs = ['events','locations','account']
 content = ""
 tabs.each do |tab|
   content << if page_id == tab
     content_tag('li', content_tag('a', tab, :href => nil ), :class => 'active')
   else
     content_tag('li', content_tag('a', tab, :href => "/#{tab}" ), :class => 'inactive')
   end
 end
 content_tag(:ul, content, :class => 'tabnav')
end
```

application.html.haml

```
%nav
  = menu_builder(@page_id)
```

And this is the source code that outputs

```
<nav>
    <ul class="tabnav">&lt;li class=&quot;active&quot;&gt;&lt;a&gt;events&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li class=&quot;inactive&quot;&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;/locations&quot;&gt;locations&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li class=&quot;inactive&quot;&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;/account&quot;&gt;account&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;</ul>
</nav>
```

I have playing around with haml_tag and so, but cannot figure how to make the menu_builder method output the correct syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace:

```
content = ""
```

with:

```
content = "".html_safe
```

Comment: or use the `raw` helper: `content = raw ""`